Getting Unidentified Image error with PIL
I've been trying to open the following Wikipedia image of a dog using PIL. What I've tried is the following.
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Dog_.jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
im = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

I was wondering about what's causing the error and if there was any work around?

If you look at the status code and the page Wikimedia returns to you, you'll see it reports an error because you have not set a reasonable value for User-Agent which makes it think you might be a "dodgy" actor.
response = requests.get(url)
print(f'{response.status_code=}')

Outputs:
 response.status_code=403


The solution is to set a valid User-Agent:
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

# Define URL and User-Agent
url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Dog_.jpg"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

# Download image
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Open with Pillow
im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

